# When should I use Pin<Arc<T>> in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm pretty new to Rust and have a couple different implementations of a method that includes a closure referencing self. To use the reference in the closure effectively, I've been using `Arc<Self>` (I am multithreading) and `Pin<Arc<Self>>`.

I would like to make this method as generally memory efficient as possible. I assume pinning the `Arc` in memory would help with this. However, (a) I've read that `Arc`s are pinned and (b) it seems like `Pin<Arc<T>>` may require additional [allocations](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/pin-arc-mutex/41940).

What is `Pin<Arc<T>>` good for?

Comment: You are misreading the linked post slightly, a `Mutex` may use a separate allocation in order to pin a system handle and the discussion there is that it could theoretically be avoided in situations where the `Mutex` itself would be pinned. So `Pin<Arc<Mutex<T>>>` could be better, not simply `Pin<Arc<T>>` in general (but `Arc<Mutex<T>>` is a very common pattern so /shrug). But besides that, you should use `Pin<Arc<T>>` when you need shared ownership of an object and you need the object to not move. What other answer could there be?

Comment: @kmdreko I guess I’m still confused by threads like this: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/can-you-get-the-raw-pointer-of-a-pinned-arc/28276/3 Is or isn’t the underlying memory for`Arc` already pinned?

Comment: Am I only pinning the Arc itself? Is that good or bad for memory efficiency?

Comment: `Arc` will allocate some space and put your object there, it won't move on its own, so in that sense yes. What `Pin` does is prevent *you* from moving it via things like `std::mem::replace` or similar. And it does this by disallowing access to the object as a `&mut T`.

Comment: `Pin` always works off of an existing pointer type like `Pin<&mut T>`, `Pin<Box<T>>`, `Pin<Arc<T>>`, etc. And the semantics are you are pinning the contents. You are not pinning the `Arc` handle itself, but even if you did so, `Pin` does not use any additional memory so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @kmdreko Okay, that clears it up I believe. So, the unique guarantee with `Pin` is that I will not move its contents. This is a compile-time guarantee. I will not be allocating any additional structures at runtime, right?

Comment: @kmdreko Even if possible in theory, `Pin` will not make `Mutex` more efficient. However, there is work being done by Mara to avoid the boxing on platforms it's not necessary (and to make `Mutex::new()` and friends `const fn`! There's already a PR for that!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `Pin` around some pointer type *does not change the behavior of the program*. It only adds a restriction on *what further code you can write* (and even that, only if the `T` in `Pin<Arc<T>>` is not `Unpin`, which most types are).

Therefore, there is no "memory efficiency" to be gained by adding `Pin`.

The only use of `Pin` is to allow working with types that *require* they be pinned to use them, such as `Future`s.